# Why does the box version of iWork '09 ask me to enter a serial number?

Tags: macos, installation, iwork

I have just purchased an iWork '09 box. After the installation, I tried to open Keynote but instead a popup appears asking me to enter a serial number. But the serial number is nowhere to be found on the box or on the DVD ... But I'm sure the box version of iWork '09 doesn't even require a serial number. So what's going on??

One thing to note is that I did install the trial version of iWork '09 before installing the full version. So I also tried removing iWork '09 trial completely before installing the full version ... no luck.

Does anyone have a clue of what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 5):

```
sudo rm -rf /Library/Application\ Support/iWork\ \'09/
```

and install from DVD once again. That did it for me.

Comment: worked perfectly. I too had installed the trial first while I waited for the boxed copy from the local apple retailer.

Answer (score 3):

I had trouble installing iWorks on my new MacBook Pro, sudo worked for me too.

I first had installed a trial version of iWork, and when I installed from my DVD I was asked for a serial number. After removing iWork the installation from DVD worked. I used the following command:

```
sudo rm -rf /Library/Application\ Support/iWork\ \'09/
```

Answer (score 1):

Apple changed their minds about serial numbers and it has caused some problems.

From [this Apple discussion thread](http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?threadID=2202953&tstart=0):

> Remove all these files:
>
> ```
> <bootVolume>:Applications: iWork '08
> <bootVolume>:library:com.apple.iWork08.Installer.plist
> <bootVolume>:library:com.apple.iWork08.plist
> <bootVolume>:Users:<userAccount>:Library:Preferences:com.apple.iWork.Keynote.plist
> <bootVolume>:Users:<userAccount>:Library:Preferences:com.apple.iWork.Numbers.plist
> <bootVolume>:Users:<userAccount>:Library:Preferences:com.apple.iWork.Pages.plist
> ```
>
> and then reinstall from the disk. (Tip from Yvan's post in [this thread](http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?threadID=1471151)).

Similarly remove any of the iWork '09 in any of those locations.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Unfortunately this doesn't work for me :(

Comment: try also http://discussions.apple.com/message.jspa?messageID=10466775#10466775

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact same problem. I tried erasing all my files that had anything to do with iWork and reinstalled it, but it kept asking me for a serial number. So I went online to [apple.com](https://www.apple.com/) and downloaded the latest updates for iWork, and now it stopped asking for any serial number and everything is working fine.